# Error network-request-failed on Firebase with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm learning ReactJS and I wanted to try it with Firebase following a small guide. I've to sign in with Google auth in Firebase but I always get this error:

> Error auth/network-request-failed: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  handleAuth() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(result => console.log(`${result.user.email} ha iniciado sesión`))
      .catch(error => console.log(`Error ${error.code}: ${error.message}`));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>ReactGIFs</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          <button onClick={this.handleAuth}>Login with Google</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the `firebase.initializeApp()` with the data copied from Firebase.
Thanks.

Comment: Okay, where is the `firebase.initializeApp()`?

Comment: In the index.js before ReactDOM.render(); I explained it bad sry

Comment: Try moving it to `componentDidMount` inside of the App component.

Comment: so how did you fix this?